# Destroy an asteroid by EM waves by making its crystalline meshes enter in resonance?

Tags: electromagnetism, resonance, asteroids

Could we destroy an asteroid made of crystalline materials heading towards the Earth by bombarding it with electromagnetic rays, making its crystalline meshes enter in vibration resonance and decompose it little by little? I estimate at first that the asteroid does not turn on itself.

If you need an example, imagine a ball of 1km radius made entirely of iron heading towards the Earth with a slightly curved trajectory at any variable speed.

Comment: "making its crystalline meshes enter in vibration resonance and decompose it little by little" do you know of a lab experiment that does this? Even if it could be done, there is conservation of energy and momentum of the mass heading towards earth, and mesh energy changes will only rearrange the mass of iron.

Comment: I don't know any experiment doing that, but breaking the bonds between the atoms could help to deviate the mass from its trajectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can,** of course, use EM radiation to break the bonds of a crystal and thus cause damage to the asteroid. In a sense, this *is* a form of "resonance" because the bonds will react to photons of some wavelengths more than of others - that's why materials have "color", after all. The trick is that you won't be able to *completely destroy* it without supplying energy approaching the order of the energy required to vaporize the asteroid, since that's pretty much what "vaporize" *means* - it means to completely dissolve the crystal lattice, so that every atom is separated from every other. **Conservation of energy cannot be cheated!**

However, a much better strategy is to **not** "completely destroy" the asteroid, but to only vaporize a little bit, so as to turn it into an exhaust plume that then produces thrust which pushes the asteroid out of its collision trajectory. Given the huge distances and times involved in a Solar orbit, even 0.1 m/s of dV could do a lot - over a year, or ~32 Ms, that's about 3200 km of deflection. If aimed right, that should convert an impact to at least a grazing pass within a few hundred km of Earth's surface for most impact cases.

And yes, a laser (EM radiation) could be an effective means and, indeed, taken literally and in light of what I just said, it pretty much *is* exactly what you are claiming - the laser photons "resonate" some of the crystal to the breaking point, sending atoms flying into space, and it happens a little at a time, but you'd have to first get one out to the asteroid, and you'd need it to keep running and aimed in the same spot for long enough to deliver the desired momentum change. There is nothing at all physically impossible about this - the challenge is all in engineering.

Heck, an arguably even simpler solution is to just focus the Sun's light directly, instead of having the laser middleman - though then you lose the advantage of being able to tune the frequency, but conversion to laser energy has inefficiency issues that likely outweigh any gains from such as being able to hit specific resonance modes maximizing surface absorption. That said, your lense or parabolic mirror will still need to be very large, so once more, engineering is going to determine what the best method is.

Answer (score 2):

This line of thought is similar to Nikola Tesla's, when he made his mechanical oscillator

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla%27s_oscillator

Idea goes like this: any object should have some resonant frequency, and if you guess this frequency correctly, you can keep pumping energy into this vibration till object is destroyed due to accumulated energy

Same line of reasoning went into many other Tesla's works, including his wireless energy transfer system for example

So, if everything is as simple as that, why dont we have any noticeable tech done this way, why is resonance restricted to carefully designed systems, and very rarely every day, natural objects?

Reason is that other than resonant frequency objects have a measure of how much energy they dissipate per oscillation. You can intuitively understand it as time of ringing. A glass will ring for quite some time, and chunk of rubber will not ring as long. It is not quite precise description, but a good start

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor

This is why Tesla's building destroying oscillator did not work - building is simply not a good oscillator. As you pump more power, building dissipates all of that power in heat in just one oscillation, and no accumulation of energy occurs even at very low movement.

There are cases when skyscrapers vibrate in a strong wind, with some accumulation of the energy between periods, but it is mostly due to how wind makes vortexes, very large amount of energy is used, and because skyscrapers are still not as bad of an oscillator as ordinary buildings or dirt would be.

Same for wireless energy transfer - most energy is lost unless very controlled environemnt and very good oscillators are in use.

And the same for your asteroid case. It is just a pile of rocks and sand bunched together. Even if there is a frequency on which it oscillates the best, it is still a very bad oscillator, and it will not accumulate energy in its vibration for more than a few oscillations.

We can evaporate parts of an asteroid with lasers, and evapotated parts provide a little bit of thrust. But because ateroids fly around at speeds on the order of 10 km/s it is hard to concentrate the laser on an asteroid for a long time. It is just too far away.

I would expect asteroid to resonate best on rotational frequency - about once per hour, on acoustic frequency - about once per few milliseconds, and plasmons in sand particles - about visible light. None of them are what people think of when talk about radio

P.S. a chunk of iron doesnt change much. It would oscillate better at acousting frequency, but it would also be much stronger mechanically. And chances to destroy it by resonance remotely are as low. Especially how hard it is to concentrate radio waves at audio frequencies. And even if you will manage using very strong lazer and jini explosions, and non-natural, single crystal asteroid, explode from resonance, it will split into a few large chunks. for planet defence it is not enough for example.